# Does the associated graded functor take products of filtered k-coalgebras to graded k-coalgebras?

Tags: homological-algebra, coalgebras, graded-rings-modules, associated-graded

Let's suppose we have two noncommutative graded k-coalgebras $C_1$ and $C_2$ with respective admissible filtrations (i.e $F_{0}C_i=0$ and $\mathrm{colim}_k F_kC_i=C_i$), I would like to know if there is an isomorphism
$$\mathrm{Gr}(C_1\prod C_2)\cong \mathrm{Gr}(C_1)\prod\mathrm{Gr}(C_2)$$
where the filtration in $C_1\prod C_2$ is $F_k(C_1\prod C_2)=\displaystyle\sum_{p+q=k}{F_pC_1\prod F_q C_2}$.
I saw the dual result for k-algebras in page 190 of the book [Cogroups and Co-rings in Categories of Associative Rings](https://books.google.fr/books?id=INbxBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=cogroups+and+corings+associated&source=bl&ots=XbOtYS726R&sig=ACfU3U0-Lt9clIIcqtmW91_gf6oTFTARbA&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMzYWIv9fhAhVLQBoKHY2-BPUQ6AEwB3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=cogroups%20and%20corings%20associated&f=false), but without proof. Any suggestion, please?.

By the way, $C_1\prod C_2=C_1\oplus C_2\oplus (C_1\otimes C_2)\oplus (C_2\otimes C_1)\oplus (C_1\otimes C_2\otimes C_1)\oplus\cdots$

the summands are alternating tensor products.

Comment: The title mentions coproducts and the notation $\prod$ stands for products.  Is that products or coproducts of coalgebras you are asking about?

Comment: Anyway, if you believe that whatever operation of two coalgebras you are interested in is computed by the formula you wrote after "by the way" -- isn't it obvious then that this commutes with the passage to the associated graded objects?  Both the direct sums and the tensor products of vector spaces do.

Comment: @leonid Sorry I actually meant product instead of coproduct in the title, already corrected.

Comment: @leonid This seems indeed evident if we define the filtration of $C_1\prod C_2$ as the induced by the expression in terms of direct sums and tensor product, but this filtration is not exactly defined in such way, unless eventualy they both agree but I am not aware of this last fact.

Comment: OK, now I see.  Presuming that the formulas for the product and for the filtration on the product are correct, the question then seems to reduce essentially to this: let $V$ be a vector space with an increasing filtration $F$ (in the situation at hand, $V=C_1$ or $V=C_2$).  Define a filtration on the tensor power $V^{\otimes n}$ (for some $n\ge1$) by the rule $F_p(V^{\otimes n})=(F_pV)^{\otimes n}$.  How to compute the associated graded vector space to $V^{\otimes n}$ with this filtration $F$?  Does the question reduce to this, indeed?

Comment: A separate issue is whether the formulas are correct.  In which category are you taking your product of two coalgebras?  All coassociative coalgebras without counit?  All conilpotent coassociative coalgebras without counit?  All filtered coassociative coalgebras without counit, with admissible filtrations?

Comment: Is $k$ a field or a commutative ring? In the latter case, how exactly are you defining filtered $k$-coalgebras? And are your filtrations filtrations in the usual sense (i.e., by subspaces/submodules), or something more general (as your use of $\operatorname{colim}$ instead of $\bigcup$ seems to suggest)?